# Replacing random numbers in a php string serial numbers(123...)

Tags: php, string, replace

In PHP, how to convert a string containing mixture of random letters and numbers to a string containing serial numbers along with random numbers without changing their position in a string? For example,

```
 $str_a = "1)Apple 5)Ball 3)Cat 8)Dog 4)Egg";
```

Now, I want to convert this string into

```
$str_b = "1)Apple 2)Ball 3)Cat 4)Dog 5)Egg";
```

I want the numbers `1,5,3,8,4` to be `1,2,3,4,5`.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Comment: Sure Brother. I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and replace each digit (`\d+` => 0-9 as many times as possible) with an incrementing number, .e.g

```
<?php

    $str_a = "1)Apple 5)Ball 3)Cat 8)Dog 4)Egg";
    $start = 1;
    echo $newStr = preg_replace_callback("/\d+/", function($m)use(&$start){
        return $start++;
    }, $str_a);

?>
```

output:

```
1)Apple 2)Ball 3)Cat 4)Dog 5)Egg
```

Comment: Great answer! nice use of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_split` and then concatenate it incrementing by 1. This will work also for numbers consisting of multiple digits:

```
$str_a = "51)Apple 675)Ball 334)Cat 84)Dog 904)Egg";
$a = preg_split('/\b\d+/', $str_a);
$str_b = '';
for($i=0,$c = count($a);$i<$c;$i++){
    if($i){
        $str_b .= $i.$a[$i];
    }
}
echo $str_b;
```

Output:

```
1)Apple 2)Ball 3)Cat 4)Dog 5)Egg
```

Answer (score 0):

Created Simple looping program:

```
$str_a = "1)Apple 5)Ball 3)Cat 8)Dog 4)Egg";

function change($str_a) {
    $counter = 1;
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($str_a); $i++) {
        if(is_numeric($str_a[$i])) {
            $str_a[$i] = $counter++;
        }
    }
    return $str_a;
}
print(change($str_a))
```

Output:

> 1)Apple 2)Ball 3)Cat 4)Dog 5)Egg